# How to ignore generic argument for `#[derive(Debug)]`?

Tags: rust, macros, traits

Here's a minimal [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79bcd68221b4ee95850a94face7de073) representing the type of problem I'm running into.

```rust
use core::fmt::Debug;

pub trait Config {
    type A: Debug;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Info<T: Config> {
    pub field: T::A,
}

pub struct Conf;

impl Config for Conf {
    type A = i128;
}

fn main() {
    let s = Info::<Conf> {
        field: 123
    };
    dbg!(s);
}
```

The framework that I'm using ([Substrate](https://docs.substrate.io/)) uses this concept of a `Config` trait that aggregates all generic types for a module (pallet).

The problem is that trying to `#[derive(Debug)]` for a struct that only uses the associated types of the object `T` implementing `Config` still requires that `T` implements `Debug` itself.

```
error[E0277]: `Conf` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     dbg!(s);
   |     ^^^^^^^ `Conf` cannot be formatted using `{:?}`
   |
   = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `Conf`
   = note: add `#[derive(Debug)]` to `Conf` or manually `impl Debug for Conf`
```

Moreover, I don't have control of the implementation of the `Conf` object. Regardless, I'm not trying to print anything about the `Conf` object itself.

Is there a way to make `#[derive(Debug)]` for `Info` ignore `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not as of today. You have to impl `Debug` manually:

```rust
impl<T: Config> fmt::Debug for Info<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("Info").field("field", &self.field).finish()
    }
}
```

There is an intent to make it possible to create what is called "perfect derive": derive bounds based on what needed and not the generic parameters. See for example [this lang team design meeting proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/152). But for now there is nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the references. At least I'll learn more about the Rust internals

Answer (score 0):

The [`derive_where` crate](https://crates.io/crates/derive-where) can be used to achieve this:

```rust
#[derive_where(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Info<T: Config> {
    pub field: T::A,
}
```